# how to remove event listener of event.js and bootstrap.min.js using javascript or typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, focus, bootstrap-modal, blockly

```
document.removeEventListener('focus', function(){
  console.log("Remove Focus")
});
```

I can remove event listener manually from the developer tools window in my browser.

But, I am not able to remove it using the above code.

Comment: You are required to post your code here, within your question, and not any third party site and definitely NO IMAGES! [mcve]

Comment: Title had incorrect grammar and the content of the question was badly formatted.